# Unable to scrape different company names from a static webpage using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script to collect the different company names from this [website](https://clutch.co/agencies/digital-marketing) using the requests module, but when I execute the script, it ends up getting nothing. I looked for the company names in the page source and found that the names are available there, so they seem to be static.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://clutch.co/agencies/digital-marketing'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("h3.company_info > a"):
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there.* What do you find in your `soup`?

Comment: The site's protected by Cloudflare so your best bet is `selenium`.

Comment: Thanks t o you dear Code-Apprentice for adding you ideas - i am glad - and i love the article

Answer (score 7):

Based on the output of the code below your site returns a `status code` of `403`, *which means that a client is forbidden from accessing a valid URL.*

The headers of this response indicate that the site is protected by `Cloudflare`

> 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '78d95f0bafebad68-ATL'

```
import requests

link = 'https://clutch.co/agencies/digital-marketing'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    print(res.status_code)
    403
    print('\n')
    print(res.headers)
    {'Date': 'Sun, 22 Jan 2023 15:37:30 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'close', 'Permissions-Policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=SR3boTo67liuRCP9u9YJcmvRZKWm5jFrnJcxtKXB42c-1674401850-0-AWOak5THdaypQLptfJnLhSTY5z2JO5+6rWurdKJQLQBPXB5tYhE0Z4NYGvJ3mjcG89KTFEkgKruhJ8XN/kTnfpo=; path=/; expires=Sun, 22-Jan-23 16:07:30 GMT; domain=.clutch.co; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=2592000', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '78d95f0bafebad68-ATL', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'}
```

Since the website's protected by Cloudflare there's a python module called [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) that attempts to bypass Cloudflare's anti-bot page.

Using the module you could be able to get the data you need.

For example:

```py
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
source_html = scraper.get("https://clutch.co/agencies/digital-marketing").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_html, "lxml")
company_data = [
    [item.getText(strip=True), f"https://clutch.co{item['href']}"]
    for item in soup.select("h3.company_info > a")
]

df = pd.DataFrame(company_data, columns=["Company", "URL"])
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="github", showindex=False))
```

This should print:

```
| Company                          | URL                                                        |
|----------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
| WebFX                            | https://clutch.co/profile/webfx                            |
| Ignite Visibility                | https://clutch.co/profile/ignite-visibility                |
| SocialSEO                        | https://clutch.co/profile/socialseo                        |
| Lilo Social                      | https://clutch.co/profile/lilo-social                      |
| Favoured                         | https://clutch.co/profile/favoured                         |
| Power Digital                    | https://clutch.co/profile/power-digital                    |
| Belkins                          | https://clutch.co/profile/belkins                          |
| SmartSites                       | https://clutch.co/profile/smartsites                       |
| Straight North                   | https://clutch.co/profile/straight-north                   |
| Victorious                       | https://clutch.co/profile/victorious                       |
| Uplers                           | https://clutch.co/profile/uplers                           |
| Daniel Brian Advertising         | https://clutch.co/profile/daniel-brian-advertising         |
| Thrive Internet Marketing Agency | https://clutch.co/profile/thrive-internet-marketing-agency |
| Big Leap                         | https://clutch.co/profile/big-leap                         |
| Mad Fish Digital                 | https://clutch.co/profile/mad-fish-digital                 |
| Razor Rank                       | https://clutch.co/profile/razor-rank                       |
| Brolik                           | https://clutch.co/profile/brolik                           |
| Search Berg                      | https://clutch.co/profile/search-berg                      |
| Socialfix Media                  | https://clutch.co/profile/socialfix-media                  |
| Kanbar Digital, LLC              | https://clutch.co/profile/kanbar-digital                   |
| NextLeft                         | https://clutch.co/profile/nextleft                         |
| Fruition                         | https://clutch.co/profile/fruition                         |
| Impactable                       | https://clutch.co/profile/impactable                       |
| Lets Tok                         | https://clutch.co/profile/lets-tok                         |
| Pyxl                             | https://clutch.co/profile/pyxl                             |
| Sagefrog Marketing Group         | https://clutch.co/profile/sagefrog-marketing-group         |
| Foreignerds INC.                 | https://clutch.co/profile/foreignerds                      |
| Social Driver                    | https://clutch.co/profile/social-driver                    |
| 3 Media Web                      | https://clutch.co/profile/3-media-web                      |
| Brand Vision                     | https://clutch.co/profile/brand-vision-1                   |
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggested script ended up getting nothing. I even switched to a different location using a VPN before executing the script, but no luck.

Comment: It might have to do with your location and the VPN servers you use. I'm guessing you scrape a lot and your IP(s) might be already getting blacklisted. I've tried the script with couple of VPN locations (Germany, France, the UK, and Sweden) and it worked each time. Try some proxy or use a decent VPN service.

Comment: This works. It works from Japan. From Netherlands. From the US. It works from a couple of TOR exit nodes. From good and bad VPNs. With eyes closed and opened as well, night and day. Bounty should be awarded to this answer.

Comment: This code worked on my system without a VPN and with a VPN. @baduker answer is correct, which is why I upvoted it.

Comment: @MITHU have you manged to retest the code?

Comment: I've attempted it countless times with no success. Give [this demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y03kstyorb2vvf/demo.mp4?dl=0) a go to see what happens @baduker.

Comment: What's that VPN you're using?

Comment: Never mind, I've found your VPN. It's not the code but *your* VPN and/or connection. *Betternet's Free VPN isn't safe or reliable. Its speeds are throttled, it has a weak privacy policy, and it lacks basic security features.* - [source](https://www.top10vpn.com/reviews/betternet-free/) or *Betternet has been caught embedding malware and tracking libraries into their VPN apps* [source](https://restoreprivacy.com/vpn/reviews/betternet/).

Comment: Just clicking "download free" triggers [this warning](https://imgur.com/a/hOhk4GR).

Comment: My guess is that the VPN you're using might not be even hiding your public IP and/or the VPN servers are already blacklisted. I wouldn't be surprised if it has IPv4 leaks, IPv6 leaks, and maybe even DNS leaks. Also, it doesn't have a kill switch, which blocks your traffic to keep your data safe if the VPN connection drops.

Comment: Your guess regarding betternet might be right. The thing is, I've found success in most of the blocking cases using that VPN, so I went for it. However, I've used the rotation of proxies taken from a few free proxy sites within the script you provided but have had no luck either. This is the first time I've failed despite using proxies.

Comment: Baduker you are a true hero and again you have provided the whole community with good impulses and a pretty cool solution. Many thanks for all you do here. Just awesome 

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

link = 'https://clutch.co/agencies/digital-marketing'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the website
driver.get(link)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(5)

# Get the page source
html = driver.page_source

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Find all elements with class "company_info" and extract the text
for item in soup.select("h3.company_info > a"):
    print(item.text)
    
# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).